# Storing MySQL data in variables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm in the process of making a forum, I'm trying to take values from a MySQL and put them in the `$f_id`, `$f_name`, `$f_desc` and `$f_date"` variables. It's not working for some reason:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   require"db_connect.php";
   $sql = "SELECT forum_id, forum_name, forum_desc, forum_date FROM forum_tbl";     
      if ($query = $db->prepare($sql)){
      $query->bind_result($f_id, $f_name, $f_desc, $f_date);
      $query->execute();  
   }else{
      echo $db->error;
   }
?>
```

And the contents of `connect.php`:

```
<?php
     $db = new mysql("DOMAIN","USERNAME","PASSWORD") or die ("ERROR");
?>
```

Comment: what are you getting returned for an error?

Comment: Are any error messages displayed?  When you say "It's not working" what do you mean exactly?  What indicates that its not working?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues.

- As [answered by Ridz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18771979/164998), it's not `mysql` it's `mysqli`.
- You need to call `execute()` before [`bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)
- You are not *fetching* your results.

  ```
  if ($query = $db->prepare($sql)){
     $query->execute();  
     $query->bind_result($f_id, $f_name, $f_desc, $f_date);   
  }

  // fetch results
  while ($query->fetch()) {
      echo $f_id, $f_name, $f_desc, $f_date;
  }
  ```

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

bind_result is a mysqli function.

```
$db = new mysqli("DOMAIN","USERNAME","PASSWORD") or die ("ERROR");
```

Comment: + this is at least part of the problem.